# Show Google Picker in a Google Apps Script in G-Suite Enterprise without access to GCP

Tags: google-apps-script, google-picker

Per the documentation ([here](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/) and [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/picker)), you need to create an API key in the developer console. We use G-Suite Enterprise and our G-Suite admins have blocked the ability for users to do anything in the developer console.

I have a Sheets bounded GAS project that is deployed as a web-app and set to execute as me. I want to show the Google Picker dialog such that users can upload files and/or select files from THEIR Google Drive.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this possible?

#### Answer:

*No, this is not possible. An API key* ***must*** *be created and for this developer console access is required.*

#### Further steps:

You need to contact your G Suite admins to allow Developer console access in order to create GCP projects. For security reasons there isn't a way around this and unfortunately there is little that the Stack Overflow community would be able to help you with regarding this.

#### References:

- [Picker API Developer's Guide](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/)
- [Display the Google Picker - Drive API v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/picker)